# Tweak jackson polymorphic deserialization

Tags: jackson, deserialization

I have a simple polymorphic model like this

```
public class Foo {

    private Bar bar1;

    private Bar bar2;

    public Bar getBar1() {
        return bar1;
    }

    public Bar getBar2() {
        return bar2;
    }

    public void setBar1(Bar bar1) {
        this.bar1 = bar1;
    }

    public void setBar2(Bar bar2) {
        this.bar2 = bar2;
    }

}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@type")
public class Bar {

}


public class BarExpression extends Bar {

    private String expression;

    public String getExpression() {
        return expression;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Object getValue() {
        return null;
    }

    public void setExpression(String expression) {
        this.expression = expression;
    }
}

public class BarLiteral extends Bar {

    private String value;

    private String type;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Serializing a simple example like this

```
public void run() throws Exception {
    Foo foo;
    BarLiteral bar1;
    BarExpression bar2;
    //
    foo = new Foo();
    bar1 = new BarLiteral();
    bar1.setType("java.lang.String");
    bar1.setValue("gnu");
    foo.setBar1(bar1);
    bar2 = new BarExpression();
    bar2.setExpression("bean.property * 2");
    foo.setBar2(bar2);
    //
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
    mapper.writeValue(w, foo);
    System.out.println(w.toString());
}
```

gives the expected result:

```
{
  "bar1" : {
    "@type" : "de.mit.jackson.BarLiteral",
    "value" : "gnu",
    "type" : "java.lang.String"
  },
  "bar2" : {
    "@type" : "de.mit.jackson.BarExpression",
    "expression" : "bean.property * 2"
  }
}
```

The question is now: I want to improve user experience when handwriting this "DSL" by supporting "primitive shortcuts" for the typed "Bar..." classes like this

```
{
  "bar1" : "gnu",
  "bar2" : "@{bean.property * 2}"
}
```

The solution that came closest was using a converter on Foo#bar1 and Foo#bar2, checking for either String or "Bar" input, but this solution requires decoration of every attribute definition.

Creating a deserializer with a comparable behavior did not work, as the @JsonTypeInfo is not compatible in the sense that i can have a @JsonDeserialize implementation that will check for a String event and then delegate to the standard @JsonTypeInfo process. The @JsonTypeInfo standard will check only for the @type and then delegate back to the (subtype) deserializer which is again my wrapper implementation.

The required process is

```
if input event is string {
   parse and return string input
} else {
   activate @type parsing delegate;
   after @type parsing activate standard BeanDeserializer 
   (**not** my implementation)
}
```

Is there another hook i am missing?